# Bulk Insert with Limited Disk Space

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I have a bit of a strange situation, and I'm wondering if anyone would have any ideas how to proceed.

I'm trying to bulk load a 48 gig pipe-delimited file into a table in SQL Server 2008, using a pretty simple bulk insert statement.

```
BULK INSERT ItemMovement
FROM 'E:\SQLexp\itemmove.csv'
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '|', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' )
```

Originally, I was trying to load directly into the `ItemMovement` table. But unfortunately, there's a primary key violation somewhere in this giant file. I created a temporary table to load this file to instead, and I'm planning on selecting distinct rows from the temporary table and merging them into the permanent table.

However, I keep running into space issues. The drive I'm working with is a total of 200 gigs, and 89 gigs are already devoted to both my CSV file and other database information. Every time I try to do my insertion, even with my recovery model set to "Simple", I get the following error (after 9.5 hours of course):

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 1
>   The transaction log for database 'MyData' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

Basically, my question boils down to two things.

1. Is there any way to load this file into a table that won't fill up the drive with logging? Simple Recovery doesn't seem to be enough by itself.
2. If we do manage to load up the table, is there a way to do a distinct merge that removes the items from the source table while it's doing the query (for space reasons)?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: For minimally logging: 1.) Don't have indexes on your temp tables; 2.) use `TABLOCK` on your temp table.  This is covered [in this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1185/minimally-logging-bulk-load-inserts-into-sql-server/).  For #2, not that I know of -- but once the data is materialized, you can build a proper index on your PK and then iterate in chunks over the data, using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, which is quite efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tommy_o was right about using TABLOCK in order to get my information loaded. Not only did it run in about an hour and a half instead of nine hours, but it barely increased my log size.

For the second part, I realized I could free up quite a bit of space by deleting my CSV after the load, which gave me enough space to get the tables merged.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Even with simple recovery the insert is still a single operation.

You are getting the error on the PK column
I assume the PK is only a fraction of the total size
I would break it up to only insert the PK
Pretty sure you can limit the columns with FORMATFILE

If you have to edit a bunch of duplicate PKs you may need use a program to parse and then load row by row

Sounds like a lot of work that is solved with a $100 drive.
For real would install a drive and use it for the transaction log.

Comment: Unfortunately, not my machine, or I would agree about the drive. Trying to see about ways around this issue from the SQL side since this should really be a one time thing.

Comment: But I gave you and answer on the SQL side.  Only load the PK.